# Bundle не работает как статический сайт

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

При запуске React приложения через открытие `index.html` - белый экран. Такое ощущение, что `bundle.js` вообще не запускается.

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const webpack = require('webpack');



module.exports = {
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: ['babel-polyfill','./src/index.js'],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/public/'
    },
    performance: {
        hints: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "warning" : false
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), path.join(__dirname, 'public')],
        watchContentBase: true,
        hotOnly: true,
        stats: 'errors-only',
        historyApiFallback:{
            index:'./src/index.html'
        },
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: ['env', 'react', 'stage-1']
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },


            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'style-loader' // creates style nodes from JS strings
                    }, {
                        loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
                    }, {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: [
                                autoprefixer({
                                    browsers: ['ie >= 8', 'last 4 version']
                                })
                            ],
                            sourceMap: true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader' // compiles Sass to CSS
                    }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ["style-loader","css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svg|jpg|png)$/i,
                // include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 1000,
                            mimetype: 'application/font-woff'
                        }
                    }

                ]
            }
            ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
        })
    ],
};
```

Код html и sources:
[image: Код html и sources:]

Как это можно исправить? Спасибо!

Comment: А что ожидалось?

Answer (score 0):

bundle.js у вас загрузился. Чтобы приложение отобразилось, его надо запустить. Надо или в bundle.js или скриптом в самой странице выполнить (если приложение, например, называется App):

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        ReactDOM.render(
            React.createElement(
                App, {}
            ), document.getElementById("root")
        );
    });
</script>
```